# $x^2e^{-nx}$ converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

wts: $f_n(x)=x^2e^{-nx}$ converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$ to $0$

If we set $f'_n(x)=0$, we get $f'_n(x)=(x)(e^{nx})(2-nx)$ and thus our critical points are $0$ and $2/n$.

$f''_n(x)=e^{-nx}(2-4nx+n^2x^2)$ and therefore $f''_n(0)=2$ tells us that $x=0$ is a minimum and $f''_n(2/n)=-2e^{-2}$ tells us that $x=2/n$ is a max.

$f_n(2/n)=\frac{4}{n^2e^2}$ is therefore our max.

We want to choose an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n>N \Rightarrow|f_n(x)-0|=|x^2e^{-nx}|<\epsilon$. We know though that $|x^2e^{-nx}|< \frac{4}{n^2e^2}$, so we instead show that $\frac{4}{n^2e^2}<\epsilon$. That is, we want $n > \frac{2}{e\sqrt\epsilon}$.

So, we choose $N$ to be $\frac{2}{e\sqrt{\epsilon}}$. It follows then for all $n > N$, $|f_n(x)-0|=\frac{x^2}{e^{nx}}<\frac{x^2}{e^{\frac{2}{e\sqrt{\epsilon}}x}}$

I don't know where to go from here. Have I made an error?

Comment: I think simply $\|f_n\|_\infty\le f_n(\frac2n)\to0$ gives what you want.

Comment: I am just trusting you on the value you gave: $f_n(\frac2n)=\frac4{n^2\,\mathrm e^2}$.